# Generating ADB QR Code for connecting to a wireless debugging

Tags: android, debugging, apk, adb

I'm trying to generate ADB QR code for pairing. [image: Here]a decoded ADB QR code. How can I generate ?

Thanks

I encoded a QR code from Android Studio and I generate new one with raw text but it doesn't work.

Comment: Based on my rough research, it's the interaction from Android Studio is integrated into ADB directly, thus a QR code on its own won't work. You might want to check the logcat when pairing from Android Studio and [checking the source code](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/mirror-goog-studio-master-dev:android-adb/src/com/android/tools/idea/adb/wireless/).

Comment: Thanks. The integrating in my codes is difficult for me. I was expecting it only contains pairing code and IP address but it's not like that I thougt maybe.

Comment: Coincidentally, I just finished researching how it's done and posted it on [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/249230/44325), and it's using multicast DNS (mDNS). I found 2 GitHub repo, one written in Python, and another in JavaScript for its implementation, if you're interested in knowing and porting it to another language.